# Hardware requirement for video serving to 1000 concurrent users

Tags: hardware, streaming, video-streaming

Can someone help us, we are looking to roll out a video on demand platform to provide internal staff the ability to view content.

we will need to stream to 1000 users, the video files will be 720p videos of max size typical 250MB. they will all be streaming various aspects including pre-encoded & possibly encrypted videos (with codecs supplied to end users)

we have been recommended the following hardware

Intel Xeon 3.6ghz 4 core
64GB
6x 1.2TB SAS disks & 2x 800GB SSD write intensive
4x 1g NIC’s

but are trying to find a way to calculate the concurrent user load this server would be able to provide and any recommendations to meet our requirements.

Comment: Someone really did not make his homework. Standard bitratge for 720p according to my sources is 500mb. That would put 1000 users at net 5000gb. I would not use that with more than 50% load, so your 4 NIC's are not even close to what you need. HDD and SSD may work or not depending on ramdonmess. The CPU is really low end - like: grab a cheap AMD Epyc, plenty of PCIe lanes (which you need) and way more cores for similar money.

Comment: Where are you in the world?

Comment: @Chopper3 - Hertfordshire. Glad you responded I saw a brilliant answer you gave someone else working on a similar project and I noticed you mentioned this is your bag...

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic on most SE sites.

Comment: Not seen any email from you dude?

Answer (score 1):

The bandwidth depends on the codec used.  Typically you would encode video using H.264 and a 720p would not be more than 4Mb/s when streaming.  4Mb/s would stream 180MB per hour.  So depending on the length of you videos, adjust accordingly. Are you streaming CBR MPTS UDP/RTP or are you using HTTP adaptive bitrate (HLS)? You can typically stream at about 90% effective rate of the port so 900Mb/s divided by 4Mb/s would give you about 225 streams per Gig Port.  This would put you at about 900 streams for the 4 Gig-E ports.  That's if all they were doing were streaming video.